# Unable to push or pull from Xcode

Tags: xcode, git

I committed some changes in my Xcode project and tried to push them, but I am prompted with: "The local repository is out of date."

Then I tried to pull as they said, but then I am prompted with: "The working copy has conflicting, uncommitted changes."

I really need to commit these changes, and I am scared of losing them if I do any wrong step. What should I do?

Thanks

Comment: Read a Git tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A opportunity is to [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) (cache) your local changes and then `git pull` the changes from remote. Then your *local* code is `up-to-date` with the *remote*.

After pulling, with `git stash pop` your *stashed* changes would be reapplied.

But be careful, there can be merge conflicts.
Now you are able to `git commit` and `git push` your local changes to the remote repository.